# Tab key giving trouble. How can I stop this

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a login MC on frame 1, layer 1. It contains 2 input texts username and password, and a login button. Beneath the login MC is menu MC (in frame 1, layer2). Menu MC contains a series of buttons (each button loads a child swf). When I publish and press tab key, the buttons located in menu MC also get selected, which I don't want. How can I stop this? What I want is so long as I have not logged in, I should not be able to select buttons on Menu MC by means of tab key. Very good site for SOLUTIONS. Whenever I face any programming problem, I turn to to stackoverflow. Thanks in advnce.

Answer (score 2):

You can control whether a movieclip's children (or the movieclip itself) are selected when pressing tab with the `tabChildren` and `tabEnabled` properties. For example:

```
// disable selection of menu children with tab
menuMc.tabChildren = false;
```

Good luck.

Comment: not sure who downvoted you but this worked for me. simple, elegant solution to an annoying problem. thanks.